# Where to get the USA bill of lading datasets

Tags: data.gov

I need the US import bill of lading datasets. I know that it's free but I only find data vendors, like import genius.

Where can I download or buy the RAW datasets without vendors? Directly from the US CBP?

Comment: It may be this isn’t available? Or is there a low cost version?